# Split() function on Neo4j cypher doesn't work correctly

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to split a string which is "a　　b　　c　　d" by "c"

```
return split("a　　b　　c　　d", "c")
```

But cypher returns ["a b ", " d"].

Is this a bug?
If it is a function specification of split() function, how can I split a string containing multiple whitespaces with keeping them?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: It is ["a　　b　　", "　　d"].

Comment: Isn't it already same

Comment: Not same. 4 spaces has shrinked to 1 space.

Comment: This is what I get `["a　　b　　", "　　d"]`, with proper spaces

Comment: Since multiple white spaces on posted text become one space, I used Japanese multibyte space charcter for posting. Try to replace multibyte space character with 4 ascii space characters.

Comment: I got it!
I was testing split() on Neo4j-browser. Then I tried it on cypher-shell and got correct result. It means that Neo4j-browser shrinked 4 spaces to 1. Thank you for taking time to talk with me!